# std::async performance on Windows and Solaris 10

Tags: multithreading, c++11, unix, std, solaris

I'm running a simple threaded test program on both a Windows machine (compiled using MSVS2015) and a server running Solaris 10 (compiled using GCC 4.9.3). On Windows I'm getting significant performance increases from increasing the threads from 1 to the amount of cores available; however, the very same code does not see any performance gains at all on Solaris 10.

The Windows machine has 4 cores (8 logical) and the Unix machine has 8 cores (16 logical).

What could be the cause for this? I'm compiling with `-pthread`, and it *is* creating threads since it prints all the "S"es before the first "F". I don't have root access on the Solaris machine, and from what I can see there's no installed tool which I can use to view a process' affinity.

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

std::default_random_engine gen(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
std::normal_distribution<double> randn(0.0, 1.0);

double generate_randn(uint64_t iterations)
{
    // Print "S" when a thread starts
    std::cout << "S";
    std::cout.flush();

    double rvalue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        rvalue += randn(gen);
    }
    // Print "F" when a thread finishes
    std::cout << "F";
    std::cout.flush();

    return rvalue/iterations;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    uint64_t count = 100000000;
    uint32_t threads = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    double total = 0;

    std::vector<std::future<double>> futures;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2;

    // Start timing
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        // Start async tasks
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, generate_randn, count/threads));
    }
    for (auto &future : futures)
    {
        // Wait for tasks to finish
        future.wait();
        total += future.get();
    }
    // End timing
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Take the average of the threads' results
    total /= threads;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << total << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Finished in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head, try moving the declarations of `gen` and `randn` inside `generate_randn`, so that there is one RNG instance per thread instead of a single shared RNG.  I would also be interested to see the full distribution of per-thread runtimes.

Comment: You were right, it worked fine after I moved gen and randn inside generate_randn! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, classes defined by the C++ standard library do *not* have any internal locking.  Modifying an instance of a standard library class from more than one thread, or reading it from one thread while writing it from another, is undefined behavior, unless "objects of that type are explicitly specified as being sharable without data races".  ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), sections 17.6.4.10 and 17.6.5.9.)  The RNG classes are not "explicitly specified as being sharable without data races".  (`cout` is an example of a stdlib object that *is* "sharable with data races" — as long as you haven't done `ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`.)

As such, your program is *incorrect* because it accesses a global RNG object from more than one thread simultaneously; every time you request another random number, the internal state of the generator is modified.  On Solaris, this seems to result in serialization of accesses, whereas on Windows it is probably instead causing you not to get properly "random" numbers.

The cure is to create separate RNGs for each thread.  Then each thread will operate independently, and they will neither slow each other down nor step on each other's toes.  This is a special case of a very general principle: multithreading always works better the less shared data there is.

There's an additional wrinkle to worry about: each thread will call `system_clock::now` at very nearly the same time, so you *may* end up with some of the per-thread RNGs seeded with the same value.  It would be better to seed them all from a `random_device` object.  `random_device` requests random numbers from the operating system, and does not need to be seeded; but it can be very slow.  The `random_device` should be created and used inside `main`, and seeds passed to each worker function, because a global `random_device` accessed from multiple threads (as in the previous edition of this answer) is just as undefined as a global `default_random_engine`.

All told, your program should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

static double generate_randn(uint64_t iterations, unsigned int seed)
{
    // Print "S" when a thread starts
    std::cout << "S";
    std::cout.flush();

    std::default_random_engine gen(seed);
    std::normal_distribution<double> randn(0.0, 1.0);

    double rvalue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        rvalue += randn(gen);
    }
    // Print "F" when a thread finishes
    std::cout << "F";
    std::cout.flush();

    return rvalue/iterations;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    uint64_t count = 100000000;
    uint32_t threads = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    double total = 0;

    std::vector<std::future<double>> futures;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2;

    std::random_device make_seed;

    // Start timing
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        // Start async tasks
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async,
                                     generate_randn,
                                     count/threads,
                                     make_seed()));
    }
    for (auto &future : futures)
    {
        // Wait for tasks to finish
        future.wait();
        total += future.get();
    }
    // End timing
    t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Take the average of the threads' results
    total /= threads;

    std::cout << '\n' << total
              << "\nFinished in "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<
                   std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: _"Solaris' implementation of <random> has internal locking"_, FWIW the question states it's GCC 4.9, which has no locking in `<random>` on Solaris or any other platform. I'm not sure why a shared engine+distribution would be so slow, but it's UB anyway so I'm not very motivated to find out. Using one per thread is necessary for correctness, so if it also helps the performance problem that's nice :-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Do you have an alternative explanation for the phenomena?  I can't conveniently experiment on either Solaris or Windows.

Comment: My best guess would be that the different threads are being scheduled on different processors and they are constantly getting cache misses for the shared variables, so that the cache contention effectively makes them run in serial.

Answer (score 2):

(This isn't really an answer, but it won't fit into a comment, especially with the command formatting an links.)

You can profile your executable on Solaris using [Solaris Studio's `collect` utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/collect-1.html).  On Solaris, that will be able to show you where your threads are contending.

```
collect -d /tmp -p high -s all app [app args]
```

Then view the results using [the analyzer utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E54439/analyzer-1.html#scrolltoc):

```
analyzer /tmp/test.1.er &
```

Replace `/tmp/test.1.er` with the path to the output generated by a `collect` profile run.

If your threads are contending over some resource(s) as @zwol posted in his answer, you will see it.

Oracle marketing brief for the toolset can be found here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/o11-151-perf-analyzer-brief-1405338.pdf

You can also try compiling your code with Solaris Studio for more data.

Comment: Although the problem is solved already, thanks for the reply! Using Solaris Studio for the actual application I was having trouble for was something that wasn't possible, which is why I tested in GCC. I'll definitely use analyzer if I run into any similar problems later on though!